# Trying to delete the date within a range if it matches a variable in Office scripts for Excel

Tags: excel, typescript, office-scripts

I have a column with dates stored that need to be cleared if they match a variable.

I've tried a ton of different ways, but this is my most recent attempt:

```
let dateRange = selectedTable
.getColumnByName("Date")
.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal()
.getTexts();

let date: string = "12/2/2022"

console.log(dateRange);

dateRange.forEach(dates => {
  if (dates === date){
    ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents
  }
})
```

This one won't work as 'dates' is an array and can't be compared to the 'date' variable as far as I can tell.

Comment: What's your locale?  That's always the biggest pain in the arse to have deal with I reckon.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me.. I'm not sure what you're referring to. I've been learning everything on the fly

Comment: Which country are you in? i.e. what date format do you live by? 12/2/2022 could be Feb or Dec depending on where you live.

Comment: Oh.. My bad LOL. US. So the 12 is December

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two issues you might be running into here:

First: `getTexts()` returns a 2D array to preserve the row/column structure of the grid. So even though `dateRange` is a column, it's still a 2D array - something like `[['value1'], ['value2'], ...]`. You can get a single cell with the expression `dateRange[rowIndex][0]`.

Second: `ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents` is simply an enum member and does not do anything on its own. To clear the contents of a specific cell/range, you need to call the `clear()` method on the corresponding `Range` object.

Putting this together, you get the following script (assuming you've defined `selectedTable` elsewhere):

```js
  let dateRange = selectedTable
    .getColumnByName("Date")
    .getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
  let texts = dateRange.getTexts();
  let date: string = "12/2/2022"

  texts.forEach((text, row) => {
    if (text[0] === date) {
      dateRange.getCell(row, 0).clear();
    }
  })
```

Additionally, as pointed out in the comments, you should be careful about date formatting. Since you're comparing strings, this script will fail to clear cells that contain `12/02/2022`, `December 2, 2022`, etc. even though the underlying date is the same.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This worked wonderfully!! Would you happen to have some learning material (or just a bit more explanation if you could :)) that could help explain how to specify the forEach method and how text[0] works. I've been learning this as I go using the Microsoft Learn documentation and any videos I could find.... Thanks again!

Comment: Apologies for the late reply - it sounds like you're somewhat new to JS/TS, so I'd suggest getting an understanding of the basics there before diving deeper into Office Scripts. As for learning material, I personally find that I learn a lot through experimentation - one way you can do this is by recording a script and playing around with the code it generates. If there's a specific part of the answer you're confused by, though, I'd be glad to explain. Happy learning!

Comment: Np! That's what I've been doing too! I have been creating a rotating on-call schedule email for my job that uses Power Automate and Office scripts :) This is actually the 3rd one I've made within it and that part was the last bit that was stumping me! Thank again!!