# script to delete only content in an excel-worksheet

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

this is my first post here, hi to everybody. I am learning how to use Microsoft Power Automate in order to automate business-processes. I also use some Excel-functions with Power Automate, one of it is to use Excel scripts.

I try to delete **only content** from a defined range of cells, lets say **"A2:A10"**. I researched over an hour to find an answer to my question but could only find fragments to get close to the final solution.

I found the following script which deletes **all content** in a **worksheet**.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let range = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet4").getRange();
    range.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
}
```

**question**: I would like to delete content within a range **"A2:A10"** in a **table** called **"sku"**. The goal is to use the script afterwards in Power Automate.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let table = workbook.getTable("**sku**");
    range.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
}
```

I found some fragments to my questions here:
[Trying to delete the date within a range if it matches a variable in Office scripts for Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74660026/trying-to-delete-the-date-within-a-range-if-it-matches-a-variable-in-office-scri)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.clearapplyto?view=office-scripts

I appreciate any help to get this thing working.

all the best

Andrew

Comment: Better to add right tags, so right people will read this.

Answer (score 2):

This code would clear the contents from cells A1:A10

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
      let sh = workbook.getActiveWorksheet()
      sh.getRange("A2:A10").clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents)
    }
```

It doesn't delete the rows however. To delete the rows you can use code like this:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
      let sh = workbook.getActiveWorksheet()
      sh.getRange("A2:A10").delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up)
    }
```

This won't work if you're using an Excel table that has more than two columns however. You would have to delete rows 2:10 in the Excel table for all of the columns. So for a table in columns A and B with 10 rows, the code the deletes the rows would look something like this:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let sh = workbook.getActiveWorksheet()
  sh.getRange("2:10").delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up)
}
```

You can also use the `deleteRowsAt()` method of the table to delete rows from all of the columns in a table this:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
      let table = workbook.getTable("sku");
      table.deleteRowsAt(0,10)
    }
```